# query and subquery join in laravel

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel

i m trying this  on laravel but i m getting error like this

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
 LINE 3: (select * from subcategory a inner join s...
HINT: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo. (SQL: select * from 
mastercategory c
inner join 
 (select * from subcategory a inner join subling b on 
a.idsubcategory=b.idsubcategory_subcategory) on c.idcategory=a.idsubcategory_subcategory
```

i m trying to join mastercatergory with subquery of join of (subcategory and subling)

```
   $users = DB::select(DB::raw(" select *  from mastercategory c
            inner join  (select * from subcategory a inner join subling b on 
            a.idsubcategory=b.idsubcategory_subcategory) on 
            c.idcategory=a.idsubcategory_subcategory "))->get();
```

how i can accomplised this i don't want to use model thanks in advance

here is my update

```
   $users  =   DB::raw(" select a.*,b.*  from mastercategory a
                  inner join  
               (select b.*,c.* from subcategory b inner join subling c  on  
           b.idsubcategory=c.idsubcategory_subcategory) on 
          a.idcategory=b.idcategory_mastercategory");
```

why i m getting empty value

Comment: When using `DB::select(DB::raw())` you do not need to use `get();` method.So your statement should be: `$users = DB::select(DB::raw("THE_SELECTION_QUERY"));`

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal we also don't need to use `DB::raw()` with `DB::select()` as first parameter to `select()` is raw query i.e, string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $users = DB::select("select *  from mastercategory c
            inner join  (select * from subcategory a inner join subling b on 
            a.idsubcategory=b.idsubcategory_subcategory) as d on 
            c.idcategory=d.idsubcategory_subcategory");
```

When you use `DB::select` it execute the statement and return the result. You don't need to use `get` and `DB::raw` with it ([check here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries)).

You were getting this error because you didn't provide the alias for inner subquery.

Comment: If this is what you want. Please accept the answer. So it can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to name each subquery. For example, use this:

```
select * from mastercategory c
inner join 
  (select * from subcategory a 
   inner join subling b on a.idsubcategory=b.idsubcategory_subcategory) as sub 
on c.idcategory=sub.idsubcategory_subcategory
```

I've added the bolded part: a.idsubcategory=b.idsubcategory_subcategory) as **sub**